# Can One-vs-all k-NN classifier, have different values of k for each class?

Tags: knn

I have three classes and I am using k-NN to classify them. I am following one -vs-all strategy. My question is, can the three binary classifiers have different value of k?

Comment: Sure they can - but why? If you need to do so it's possible KNN isn't the right algorithm for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.I used one vs all strategy cos I  will be able to analyze each class performance individually and K-NN cos its simple but powerful also .

Comment: Also for each class I used a separate fixed K value.For class 1, I fixed K value as 3,class 2 K value as 5,class 3 K value as 7.So can I have separate K for each class ?